# Can't Log NSFetchedResultsController Fetched Objects NSarray

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nslog

Any particular reason why I can't log a NSFetchControllers fetched objects? Every time I do I get this error: **-[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feb43743f40** The results so up perfectly in the uitableview, that's not the issue, I just can log the actual fetched objects. I know the array isn't empty because I have results in the tableview. Anyone know why I can't log the array? Code below:

```
NSLog(@"fetched results objects: %@", [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]);
```

Comment: This is definitely not the line where the error occurs. The error message says somewhere a dictionary is passed where `NSString` or `NSData` (or something which responds to `length`) is expected.

Comment: I thought so to, first I commented everything out except this line and ran the code and it still errored, then I removed this line and everything ran perfectly. I also have no dictionaries anywhere in this tableviewcontroller

Comment: Is `fetchedResultsController` really an `NSFetchedResultsController` instance? That's the one and only (most unlikely) reason why this line could crash

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController, that would make it an instance of the NSFetchedResultsController correct? This is what I have

Comment: Not necessarily. That's the declaration. Where is the property initialized? But if this was not the proper class the whole table view datasource would break.

Comment: @vadian that's not possible bc I'm getting the fetch results in my table view, if the instantiation did happen how else would I be getting the fetch results displayed in the table view?